# How do I figure out what's causing Focus Assist to turn on?

Tags: windows-10, fullscreen

Windows has activated Focus Assist, thinking I have an application in full-screen mode. That is not obviously the case among any of the (many) applications I have open.

How can I tell which application is triggering this?

[image: Screenshot of focus assist notice]

Comment: Do you have multiple screens?

Comment: @music2myear Yes. In my particular case it turned out to be [a Windows bug](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/cf5cy9/focus_assist_and_chrome_maximized_window/) (for me, it was Firefox, but others have reported it being triggered by Chrome etc.). But I'll leave the question open for now; it'd be good if there were a general way to tell which application is responsible. [Windows Feedback link](https://aka.ms/AA5nqst) if anyone feels like voting for it ;)